# \usepackage{helvet} not working

Tags: packages

I need to simulate the Arial font. I am using MikeTeX with TeXmaker. So far the code below works fine, but since I copied the file on USB and transferred it to another PC, Texmaker will not work with sans-serif Helvetia.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
For plants stress is a difficult problem to tackle. 
For plants stress is a difficult problem to tackle. 
For plants stress is a difficult problem to tackle. 
For plants stress is a difficult problem to tackle. 
For plants stress is a difficult problem to tackle. 
For plants stress is a difficult problem to tackle. 

\end{document}
```

LOG FILE :

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.4.29) 20 JUN 2022 13:21
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./trail_and_fail.tex
(trail_and_fail.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count189
\Gm@cntv=\count190
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count191
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen139
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen144
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (WaS)
)
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for TU+phv on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: No file TUphv.fd. on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/phv/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xet
ex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: XeTeX
()
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count192
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\g__graphics_track_int=\count195
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count196
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count198
) (trail_and_fail.aux)
\openout1 = `trail_and_fail.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 8
.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes:
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.13188pt, 455.24411pt, 71.13188pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(71.13188pt, 717.00946pt, 56.9055pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=455.24411pt
* \textheight=717.00946pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \evensidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \topmargin=-38.1381pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <12> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <8> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <6> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/phv/b/n' undefined
(Font) using `TU/phv/m/n' instead on input line 10.
(trail_and_fail.toc)
\tf@toc=\write3
\openout3 = `trail_and_fail.toc'.
[1
] (trail_and_fail.aux)
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1136 strings out of 410967
19978 string characters out of 2823753
325495 words of memory out of 3000000
21908 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
472035 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
55i,5n,62p,353b,189s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
Output written on trail_and_fail.pdf (1 page).
```

LOG FILE when I am using PDFLatex:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.4.29) 21 JUN 2022 13:20
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./Bachelorarbeit.tex
(Bachelorarbeit.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count193
\Gm@cntv=\count194
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count195
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen139
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen144
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (WaS)
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/float\float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count196
\float@exts=\toks18
\float@box=\box50
\@float@everytoks=\toks19
\@floatcapt=\box51
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen147
))
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen148
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count198
\leftroot@=\count199
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count266
\DOTSCASE@=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
\big@size=\dimen149
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count268
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count269
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count270
\dspbrk@lvl=\count271
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count272
\column@=\count273
\maxfields@=\count274
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen150
\alignsep@=\dimen151
\tagshift@=\dimen152
\tagwidth@=\dimen153
\totwidth@=\dimen154
\lineht@=\dimen155
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2022/03/01 v3.6b Customizing captions (AR)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2022/03/17 v2.3b caption3 kernel (AR)
\caption@tempdima=\dimen156
\captionmargin=\dimen157
\caption@leftmargin=\dimen158
\caption@rightmargin=\dimen159
\caption@width=\dimen160
\caption@indent=\dimen161
\caption@parindent=\dimen162
\caption@hangindent=\dimen163
Package caption Info: Standard document class detected.
)
\c@caption@flags=\count275
\c@continuedfloat=\count276
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\subcaption.sty
Package: subcaption 2022/01/07 v1.5 Sub-captions (AR)
\c@subfigure=\count277
\c@subtable=\count278
) (C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/was\gensymb.sty
Package: gensymb 2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
fg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen164
\Gin@req@width=\dimen165
) (C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/apacite\apacite.sty
Package: apacite 2013/07/21 v6.03 APA citation
\c@BibCnt=\count279
\bibleftmargin=\skip52
\bibindent=\skip53
\bibparsep=\skip54
\bibitemsep=\skip55
\biblabelsep=\skip56
) (C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
Package: array 2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen166
\ar@mcellbox=\box54
\extrarowheight=\dimen167
\NC@list=\toks25
\extratabsurround=\skip57
\backup@length=\skip58
\ar@cellbox=\box55
)
\TX@col@width=\dimen168
\TX@old@table=\dimen169
\TX@old@col=\dimen170
\TX@target=\dimen171
\TX@delta=\dimen172
\TX@cols=\count280
\TX@ftn=\toks26
)
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for OT1+phv on input line 3
1.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1phv.fd
File: ot1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count281
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box56
) (Bachelorarbeit.aux)
\openout1 = `Bachelorarbeit.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 31.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes:
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.13188pt, 455.24411pt, 71.13188pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(71.13188pt, 717.00946pt, 56.9055pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=455.24411pt
* \textheight=717.00946pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \evensidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \topmargin=-38.1381pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
\symgns@font=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `gns@font' in version `bold'
(Font) TS1/phv/m/n --> TS1/phv/b/n on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Math companion symbols declared on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \degree on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \celsius on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Using text companion symbols for \degree, \celsius and \p
erthousand on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ohm on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Using \textohm for \ohm on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Using \textmu for \micro on input line 31.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count282
\scratchdimen=\dimen173
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count283
\nofMParguments=\count284
\everyMPshowfont=\toks27
\MPscratchCnt=\count285
\MPscratchDim=\dimen174
\MPnumerator=\count286
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count287
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks28
)
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-b
ase.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.c
fg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
\c@maskedRefs=\count288
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/apacite\english.apc
File: english.apc 2013/07/21 v6.03 apacite language file
LaTeX Info: Redefining \BPBI on input line 129.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \BHBI on input line 130.
)
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/phv/m/it' in size <17.28> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for TS1+phv on input line 3
4.
(C:\Users\janse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\ts1phv.fd
File: ts1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for TS1/phv.
)
(Bachelorarbeit.toc)
\tf@toc=\write3
\openout3 = `Bachelorarbeit.toc'.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `zhang2020thriving' undefined on input line 44.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `morgan1984osmoregulation' undefined on input line 44.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `lee1982selectivity' undefined on input line 44.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `dai2013increasing' undefined on input line 46.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `boyer1982plant' undefined on input line 46.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `lloyd2014impracticality' undefined on input line 49.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `palmer1965meteorological' undefined on input line 49.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/phv/m/it' in size <10.95> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 51.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `lal2016tenets' undefined on input line 51.
[1
{C:/Users/janse/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Warning: Citation `wmo1966international' undefined on input line 53.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `mawdsley1994assessment' undefined on input line 53.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding
/\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape
l.61 ...rought impedes seed germination \cite{•}
. Drought Stress has shown...
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
4919 strings out of 478582
83045 string characters out of 2844344
775460 words of memory out of 3000000
23053 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
490761 words of font info for 64 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
10000i,10n,19997p,642b,262s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: You don't say just what "not working" and "will not work" mean. It's not clear what the problem is or what you're asking.

Comment: shorten the example (remove all the unneeded stuff (like apacite or tabularx)) and then post the log-file.

Comment: You're requesting the wrong font encoding because you're using xelatex instead of pdflatex. For that document you should probably use pdflatex not xelatex. The `helvet` package loads the Type 1 version of the font. You could add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but you might as well use pdflatex unless you have a reason to use xelatex. If you must use xelatex, then you can get "Helvetica"/Nimbus Sans/TeX Gyre Heros using the fontspec package instead.

Comment: Hi frabjous, I tried using pdflatex. You are right, I did use this before, and then played around in the settings on the other PC. But now the file still doesn't print, and sadly I'd like to deter from the option of using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} as this is to different from the Arial font. I included now the LOG FILE of pdflatex as well. Thank you for your help already^^

Comment: Ok this error comes from using \maketitle without \title() the error I am facing can only be shown over the LOG FILE of my full document and cannot be replicated within my small sample that runs now in helvet pdflatex. I will edit to the LOG FILE of my original document.

Comment: I don't know what you mean about `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`: use that *with* `\usepackage{helvet}`, not instead of it. Either way you're not getting Arial; you're getting Nimbus Sans L, which is similar to Arial but not the same. If you want Microsoft's proprietary Arial font, you should use xelatex with the fontspec package. (Though I try to avoid proprietary-anything if I can.)

Comment: Unfortunately the new log file does not match your sample code. It references line 61 which the sample file does not have. TeX capacity exceeded errors can be caused by a lot of things. You need to whittle the new problem down to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates the new error, but maybe post in a new question since it's probably unrelated to the original issue with the  `helvet` package.